# Like SQL Query in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My problem is the following:

I'm looking for a solution in LINQ which translates a LINQ expression to SQL LIKE query.

(I know in LINQ I can use Contains, StarsWidth, EndWidth instead of 'LIKE' but in my case is not a good solution, and if you check the generated sql script you will see it is not use LIKE)

I found a lot of article that use the System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like methods
so I wrote my query:

```
var query = from c in _context.prgCity where SqlMethods.Like( c.FullName, "%buda") select c.FullName + "|" + c.prgCountry.CountryName;

return query.ToList<string>();
```

But when query is running I get the following error message:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Like(System.String, System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Anybody can Help me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to use `SqlMethods.Like` when from LINQ to Entities. As per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.like.aspx):

> This method is currently only supported in LINQ to SQL queries.

You haven't really explained why `Contains`/`StartsWith`/`EndsWith` don't work for you (and in my experience they *do* get translated into `LIKE` clauses).

Comment: I try to explain why the Startwidth method is not good for me.

Comment: @user295541: I don't find your explanation convincing.  `StartsWith` covers "term%" , `EndsWith` covers "%term", `Contains` covers "%term%".  The only time you would need "like" is if you were doing, "te%rm".  Actually, "te%rm" can be accomplished by using a `StartsWith` and an `EndsWith`.  Something like "t%e%r%m" cannot.

Answer (score 4):

You could write your query as:

```
var query = from c in _context.prgCity 
            where c.FullName.EndsWith("buda")
            select c.FullName + "|" + c.prgCountry.CountryName;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
where c.FullName.Contains("buda")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Contains instead of SQLMethods.Like. It will work.